# ExistenceCondition in Azure Policy?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm currently trying to understand the Azure policies. I think I've got my head around the aliases, but I'm having trouble understanding where to find the correct values for ExistenceCondition equals field

1. How does it different from the PolicyRule we applied?
2. Should i keep ExistanceCondition almost same as PolicyRule?

Policy rule i applied :

```
    "if":{
            "allOf":[
               {
                  "field":"type",
                  "equals":"Microsoft.Insights/metricalerts"
               },
               {
                  "field":"Microsoft.Insights/metricalerts/enabled",
                  "equals":"true"
               },
               {
                  "field":"Microsoft.Insights/metricalerts/actions[*]",
                  "less":"1"
               }
            ]
         }
```

Comment: One scenario to use `ExistenceCondition` is to check resources other than resources that `PolicyRule` specified.

Comment: For example, for all A type resources, check if exists B type resource that reference A. In this case, `PolicyRule` specifies A resources while `ExistenceCondition` specifies B resources.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @ccshih what if we ignore 'ExistenceCondition' ? documentation says that it will then not trigger the deployment. Then it should be mandatory right?

Answer (score 5):

[ExistenceCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#deployifnotexists-properties) is the opposite of `policyRule` in terms of control direction.
In policy rule you proceed only if the condition is true. in `ExistenceCondition`  you proceed only if the condition is false. In the example below in `policyRule` you filter only the storageAccount then proceed. The deploy happens only if the condition is false (deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled ==false) so it proceeds and deploy. So once deploy is done, it will be deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled ==true

```
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
                },
                {
                    "field": "kind",
                    "in": [
                        "Storage",
                        "StorageV2",
                        "BlobStorage",
                        "BlockBlobStorage"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "DeployIfNotExists",
            "details": {
                "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
                "existenceCondition": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/default.deleteRetentionPolicy.enabled",
                    "equals": true
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-effect-details#sample-2-explanation

```
"details": {
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "existenceCondition": {
        "allOf": [{
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
                "equals": "[parameters('publisher')]"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
                "equals": "[parameters('type')]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

> The **existenceCondition** uses policy language elements, such as logical
> operators, to determine if a matching related resource exists. In this
> example, the values checked against each alias are defined in
> parameters.

Comment: why we need it when there is already a policy rule?

Comment: What happens if we ignore it , it is an optional field.

Comment: "to determine if a matching related resource exists" if it exists then what? If not then what?

Answer (score 0):

ExistenceCondition apply only to policy with effect AuditIfNotExists and DeployIfNotExists.

In case of AuditIfNotExists

> "If any matching related resource evaluates to true, the effect is
> satisfied and doesn't trigger the audit."

In case of DeployIfNotExists

> "If any matching related resource evaluates to true, the effect is
> satisfied and doesn't trigger the deployment."

Existing resource which does not match ExistenceCondition will be marked as non-complaint. Resources filtered out by PolicyRule will not be marked as non-complaint.

Answer (score 0):

With `ExistenceCondition`, you can evaluate all subresources of a specific type and then base your logic around that. So `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine` could have 0-to-many `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions` sub-resources. How would you check if there is at least one extension that has the `MicrosoftWindowsServer` as publisher? You couldn't do that without the `ExistenceCondition` feature. Because if you would try to do that on a higher level, it will fail when there might be other extensions installed with a different publisher.